# attempt not working in other pages laravel

Tags: php, laravel

the auth of guard not working after redirect but if i `dd(auth::guard('staff'))` in the same page after request it shown

**web route**

```
Route::get('/dash', function () {
return view('staff.dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');

Route::controller(authController::class)->group(function () {
Route::get('/', 'index');
Route::post('/Login', 'authLogin')->name('authLogin');
});
```

**authController**

if i used the dd after the condition i got the user info when i try to use auth::guard in dashboard page i got null

i tryied to use auth()->guard same result = null

```
class authController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
     return view('auth.login');
}

public function authLogin(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    if (
        Auth::guard('staff')->attempt($credentials)
    ) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
    dd('faild');
}

}
```

**staff Model**

```
class Staff extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
use HasFactory;
use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
protected $table = 'staff';
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
    'role',
    'profileAvatar'
];
}
```

**auth.php**

```
  'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'staff' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'staffs',
    ],
],



'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => env('AUTH_MODEL', App\Models\User::class),
    ],

    'staffs' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Staff::class,
    ],
   ],
],
```

Comment: If I got it right, you are trying to implement authorization for a given page? ie, staff cant access clients/admin pages?

Comment: after attmept Auth::guard('staff') i should be able to access it from any where and that not working

Comment: what is the guard for? whats its main use? that's my question so that i can try to help you

Comment: to use authentication on the staff table

Comment: try ```'staffs' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => env('AUTH_MODEL', App\Models\Staff::class),
    ],```

Comment: is not  related the auth already work and redirect me to dashboard page but there the auth()->guard('staff') return null instade of the staff user value

Comment: then i think for it to work, as get staff details, the staffs array should be inside providers in auth.php. try it and try `auth:staff()->some_value;` instead

Comment: still not working

Comment: then remove the guard, create a middleware. I am not familiar with guards that much but middlewares works to fine, just now on the login controller, you will have a logic to differentiate a normal user and a staff

Comment: the `guard` method doesn't return a user, it returns a guard .... you keep saying you get `null` for something, what are you getting `null` for? show the code

Comment: Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard {#428 ▼ // routes\web.php:17
  +name: "staff"
  #lastAttempted: null
  #viaRemember: false
.
.
.
#user: null

Comment: the user should carry the information of the authenticated user from authLogin function in the controller